# UICollectionViewLayout: add DecorationView only to specific cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionreusableview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I've developed a custom CollectionViewLayout which uses `DecorationView` to show shadows behind the cells.

However, I'd like to add this decoration only to some cells. The `UICollectionView` is `vertical`, but it may contain an embedded `horizontal` `UICollectionView` inside the cell. The cells with an embedded `UICollectionView` should not be decorated, as shown on the image:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to add a shadow. The `UICollectionViewLayout` does not provide a method how to retrieve a cell's class, so it could decide whether to add a shadow or not:

```
  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let parent = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    guard let attributes = parent, !attributes.isEmpty else {
      return parent
    }

    let sections = attributes.map{$0.indexPath.section}
    let unique = Array(Set(sections))


    // Need to detect, which sections contain an embedded UICollectionView and exclude them from the UNIQUE set


    let backgroundShadowAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = unique.compactMap{ section in
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)
      return self.layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind: backgroundViewClass.reuseIdentifier(),
                                                    at: indexPath)
    }

    return attributes + backgroundShadowAttributes + separators
  }
```

Is there any way to conditionally specify, which views should be decorated?

Comment: Why you can't create custom  cell class with the shadow and create appropriate paddings in the UICollectionViewLayout?

Comment: There are more complex cases, when the `UICollectionView` should look like a `UITableView` and have shadows rendered correctly. Attaching a shadow to a `UICollectionViewCell` does not work in such a case:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVKoY.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finished with this code:
A protocol to directly ask the DataSource, whether to show a shadow for a particular section:

```
protocol SectionBackgroundFlowLayoutDataSource {
  func shouldDisplayBackgroundFor(section: Int) -> Bool
}
```

And leverage the protocol in the `func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` method:

```
  override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    let parent = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    guard let attributes = parent, !attributes.isEmpty else {
      return parent
    }

    attributes.forEach(configureRoundCornersAttributes)

    // Display shadows for every section by default
    var sectionsWithShadow = Set(attributes.map{$0.indexPath.section})
    if let dataSource = collectionView?.dataSource as? SectionBackgroundFlowLayoutDataSource {
    // Ask DataSource for sections with shadows, if it supports the protocol
      sectionsWithShadow = sectionsWithShadow.filter{dataSource.shouldDisplayBackgroundFor(section: $0)}
    }

    let backgroundShadowAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = sectionsWithShadow.compactMap{ section in
      let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)
      return self.layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind: backgroundViewClass.reuseIdentifier(),
                                                    at: indexPath)
    }

    return attributes + backgroundShadowAttributes + separators
  }
```

`func shouldDisplayBackgroundFor(section: Int) -> Bool` may return faster, than `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, as it doesn't require full cell configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Would it be possible to post the whole code for your collectionviewflowlayout subclass, as I'm trying to do the exact same thing and I'm struggling!